# Show two types of items, one more important than the other in an application

Tags: interface

I'm building a mobile application for an events-management company which mainly organize medical or orthodontics congresses.

In the first screen they would like to show the events that they have planned, together with some articles about new technologies in the medical world, interviews that they will write weekly.

Since they are more interested in people coming to their events than people reading their articles they asked me to keep them mixed in the same page, ordered by publication date, but giving more priority to the events than the article.

How can i achieve this in a small space like a smartphone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Material Design than it won't be a problem.

Make a big card approx. 45% of screen height for Event and slim cards for articles.

Use bright color for event card and some cold color for articles (all article must be of same color so that they will look like normal cards.

It will be better if you use proper shadow and transition effect for event card.

Comment: http://oi64.tinypic.com/2uz3ujd.jpg 
Thank you very much it worked very well. What do you think about responsiveness instead ? In the phone they are piled one above the other but on a tablet i can put them one near the other but there are height problems

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to use distinguishably different background colors for events and articles, [image] and priorities would accordingly be set. This way, you'd be able to come around the space constraint, and as a bonus, would be able to create a particular theme, which could be used to keep the users familiar with the application if it's platforms are to be extended in the future.

Garnish with creativity.

Comment: Do you know a nice way that could work with Material Design specifications ?